# How to order by ASC, but to sort null at the last in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have the below query in mysql, which sorts rows in ascending order of `rm.meta_val`. But in addition I want the null `meta_val` rows to be positioned at the last.
Could anyone help out?

```
SELECT rt.tax_id,ra.*,
FROM req_tax rt, req_aspects ra, req_meta rm 
where ra.aspect_id = rt.req_aspects_id 
      and rt.tax_id=rm.req_tax_id
      and rm.req_id = rt.req_id  and rt.requests_id = 18 
group by rt.tax_id 
ORDER BY rm.meta_val asc;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `IF` in the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
ORDER BY 
   IF(rm.meta_val IS NULL, 1, 0),
   rm.meta_val asc;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can sort on a function result, so use an `if` to check whether the value is null, and if so return a very high value, otherwise return the value. Ideally, you would choose a value of the same type (number of bits, signed vs unsigned) based on the Max value being sorted plus one, as this avoids type promotion, but that may not be important to you. Switch the if returns if you want the nulls on the other end

```
SELECT rt.tax_id,ra.*, 
FROM req_tax rt, req_aspects ra, req_meta rm 
WHERE ra.aspect_id = rt.req_aspects_id
  AND rt.tax_id=rm.req_tax_id
  AND rm.req_id = rt.req_id
  AND rt.requests_id = 18 
GROUP BY rt.tax_id 
ORDER BY if(rm.meta_val is NULL, 0xFFFFFFFF, rm.meta_val) asc;
```

Answer (score 0):

try with `case`:

```
 SELECT rt.tax_id,ra.*,
    FROM req_tax rt, req_aspects ra, req_meta rm where ra.aspect_id = rt.req_aspects_id 
    and rt.tax_id=rm.req_tax_id and rm.req_id = rt.req_id  and rt.requests_id = 18 group by rt.tax_id 
 order by case when rm.meta_val is null then 1 else 0 end, rm.meta_val
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query use `ISNULL`:-

```
order by ISNULL(rm.meta_val), rm.meta_val ASC
```

Your query like that :-

```
SELECT rt.tax_id,ra.*,
FROM req_tax rt, req_aspects ra, req_meta rm where ra.aspect_id = rt.req_aspects_id 
and rt.tax_id=rm.req_tax_id
and rm.req_id = rt.req_id  and rt.requests_id = 18 group by rt.tax_id order by ISNULL(rm.meta_val), rm.meta_val ASC;
```